# Issue with aligning table cell exactly on dotted line

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have dotted line separating two rows of the table like below.

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Issue</td>                               
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>  
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px dotted red;padding-top:2px;width:800px;"></td>
    <tr>
        <td>Theres is a issue with the code</td>
        <td>09-28-2012</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is [fiddler version](http://jsfiddle.net/dPY7D/). I want to align that date on line somewhere not at the end. How can I do that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dPY7D/1/ like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `colspan = "2"` to the `td` that has the dotted line. [`colspan`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) and [`rowspan`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) define how many columns or rows the cell spans, respectively.

Here's a modified version of your demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/aQcYm/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<table cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
    <td>Issue</td>                               
    <td >Date</td>
 </tr>  
 <tr>
   <td class="td"></td>
   <td class="td"></td>
 <tr>    
 <tr>
    <td>Theres is a issue with the code</td>
    <td>09-28-2012</td>
 </tr>
</table>​
```

CSS:

```
.td{
   border-bottom: 1px dotted red;width:800px;padding-top:2px;
   }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/q3AaZ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
 <table cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Issue</td>                               
            <td>Date</td>
        </tr>  
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted red;padding-top:2px;width:800px;"><td></td><td ></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Theres is a issue with the code</td>
            <td>09-28-2012</td></tr>
    </table>
```